# how to create setup of database

Tags: .net, database, installation, window

how to create setup of database. I have windows application in c#.net i am able to create setup of my application in vs2008  but i want to create my MySql database server setup for multiple clients of my application. Please help me...

Comment: Can you provide more information? There isn't much detail on what you want, apart from being able to "setup" your database.

Comment: i want to ask how to make setup and install database(MySql) of my  application(c#.net) on server machine? and how to change connection string of client application related to server

Answer (score 1):

mySQL Database Setup

http://developedtraffic.com/resources/mysql-database.php

How to Setup a MySQL Database

http://www.webwisesage.com/addons/free_ebook.html

Database Setup For MySQL - Confluence Docs 3.2 - Atlassian ...

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Database+Setup+For+MySQL

MySQL Tutorial - Setup

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsetup.php

i Think this above links will help you

Answer (score 0):

2 Main steps will have to happen:

1. MySQL will have to be installed on the client
2. Your database will have to be created.

For Step 2 I recommend creating a script of your databse in the 'inital' state or however your client(s) expect the database to be when they start using your application.

**You may be able to use Visual Studio's SQL Database publishing wizard to automatically create a script which will create your database
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120730025352/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx)**

You can instruct your client to run the .sql script or you may be able to call mysql from the command line to run the script as part of an installer.

I have done a similar procedure with SQL Server applications, so I would expect this should work similarly